# Is it possible to wrap date line with gdal.VectorTranslate()?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, antimeridian

I use '-wrapdateline' option in ogr2ogr to split the polygons at the anti meridian. But in [ogr2ogr Python port](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/77544764f51420e42468641fc3d5a087f8ea6d8f/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py) bWrapDateline is hardcoded to False.

Is there a way to pass 'wrapdateline' option to gdal.VectorTranslate() to split a single polygon into a multipolygon? I'm using GDAL 2.1.0

Comment: can't you just split the polygon with a line at 180?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: It is a Python script. Just edit it with text editor, change false into true and save.

Comment: @user30184, changing to true didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL >= 2.2 supports GeoJSON  RFC7946 standart. Geometries across the antimeridian are split automatically. See [autotests](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/3f41b569448513ee206efddd39a7528231bda718/autotest/ogr/ogr_geojson.py#L3032)

Sample code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import json


def read_file(filename):
    vsifile = gdal.VSIFOpenL(filename,'r')
    gdal.VSIFSeekL(vsifile, 0, 2)
    vsileng = gdal.VSIFTellL(vsifile)
    gdal.VSIFSeekL(vsifile, 0, 0)
    return gdal.VSIFReadL(1, vsileng, vsifile)

gdal.UseExceptions() #Fail when can't open!

gdal.VectorTranslate('/vsimem/out.json', """{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates":[[[-188.56933593749997,61.58549218152362],[-173.9794921875,61.58549218152362],[-173.9794921875,66.00015035652659],[-188.56933593749997,66.00015035652659],[-188.56933593749997,61.58549218152362]]] } },
  ]
}""", format = 'GeoJSON', layerCreationOptions = ['RFC7946=YES', 'WRITE_BBOX=YES'])

got = read_file('/vsimem/out.json')

print json.loads(got)
```

Output:

```
{u'type': u'FeatureCollection', u'bbox': [171.4306641, 61.5854922, -173.9794922, 66.0001504], u'features': [{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[-180.0, 66.0001504], [-180.0, 61.5854922], [-173.9794922, 61.5854922], [-173.9794922, 66.0001504], [-180.0, 66.0001504]]], [[[180.0, 61.5854922], [180.0, 66.0001504], [171.4306641, 66.0001504], [171.4306641, 61.5854922], [180.0, 61.5854922]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {}, u'bbox': [171.4306641, 61.5854922, -173.9794922, 66.0001504]}]}
```

Comment: This code has some (minor) issues, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255168/2856